# Link to first image attachment in a wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How would I create a text link to the first image attachment page in a wordpress post without trying to figure out what the slug will be after it is published.  I realize that I can link the images to their attachment page but I wan't to be able to create a text link.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<?php  
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'offset' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    );
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        if(wp_attachment_is_image( $attachment->ID )) {
        echo '<a href="'. get_attachment_link($attachment->ID) . '">LINK TEXT HERE</a>';
        break;
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You'd get exactly the same result if you limited that `get_posts` call to one post, eg. `'numberposts' => 1,` ... (which would be a little better then selecting every associated attachment just to display one).

Comment: That makes perfect sense, don't know why I have "-1".  Thanks.